# Function not using arguments values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to reuse a function, but it's not getting the arguments values:

```
function has_children($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1.'<br>'.$arg2;
    $children = get_term_children( $arg1, 'area' );
    if(empty($children)){
        $term_children_slug = $arg2;
    }
}
```

One of the places where it is used

```
if (is_tax('area')){
    $term_slug = $queried_object->slug;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
    has_children($term_id, $term_slug);
}
```

The values are printed but not used inside the function.

Comment: If you try `echo $children` is there anything displayed?

Comment: Do you see that echo? `echo $arg1.'<br>'.$arg2;`?

Comment: What is `$term_children_slug`? It looks like a global, but you don't declare it as such in your function...

Comment: @VeeeneX Yes, I see the values that I need to use.

Comment: @marcelo2605 is $term_children_slug a global var?

Comment: @VeeeneX No, it not, because it's value change based on 'if' result

Comment: @marcelo2605 If variable is declared in function scope then it cannot be accessible, outside it.

Comment: What do you get when you echo out `$arg1` in `get_term_children()`?

Comment: @VeeeneX You mean I can't use $term_children_slug outside has_children function?

Comment: @VeeeneX. Thanks for the explanation. Is there another way for not copy this function in everywhere?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Can you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `$term_children_slug`, when it isn't declared as global in function scope.

```
function has_children($arg1, $arg2){
    /* Return type 1 */
    $term_children_slug = '';

    echo $arg1.'<br>'.$arg2; // args printed here
    $children = get_term_children( $arg1, 'area' ); // not used here?
    if(empty($children)){
        $term_children_slug = $arg2;
    }
    /* Return type 2-Remove Comments and return type 1
    return (isset($term_children_slug)) ? $term_children_slug : '';
    */

    /* Return type 1 */
    return $term_children_slug;
}
if (is_tax('area')){
    $term_slug = $queried_object->slug;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
    /* If you want to get result */
    $result = has_children($term_id, $term_slug);
}
```

For more details check *didierc answer*

Comment: Note that you only return something if `$children` is empty.

Comment: @didierc What about now, restful :D

Comment: Well, that's good enough. If you want an advice, I would avoid returning values of different types (although it's common practice in PHP), because it makes it harder to reason upon, if for instance you need to pass the function around. That being said, I don't know the type of values expected by Op.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
function has_children($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1.'<br>'.$arg2; // args printed here
    $children = get_term_children( $arg1, 'area' ); // not used here?
    if(empty($children)){
        $term_children_slug = $arg2;
    }
}
```

How do you know they are not used in the function? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect the function define the correct value to $term_children_slug variable, based on the condition.

Comment: `$term_children_slug` is not in your scope. Either make it global in `has_children()` or make `has_children()` return a value and assign it to `$term_children_slug`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

As it stands, your function has no visible side effects: it calls a function whose purpose is unknown, and modify a variable which is not declared global or returned by the function.

#### Possible fixes

Import the global in the function scope:

```
function has_children($arg1, $arg2) {
  global $term_children_slug;
  echo $arg1.'<br>'.$arg2;
  $children = get_term_children( $arg1, 'area' );
  if(empty($children)){
    $term_children_slug = $arg2;
  }
}
```

Return the computed value:

```
function has_children($arg1, $arg2) {
  $term_children_slug = 'default values';
  echo $arg1.'<br>'.$arg2;
  $children = get_term_children( $arg1, 'area' );
  if(empty($children)){
    $term_children_slug = $arg2;
  }
  return $term_children_slug;
}
```

Don't forget to initialise the variable with a default value (could be a value from `$children`).

Comment: True, but that's another problem. Not knowing the remaining of OP's code, I cannot know which fix will more likely fit his codebase.